# Is Singleton with an Entity Framework dbcontext good?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, singleton, dbcontext

My question is too simple, I have an idea to manage a `DbContext` object by using one instance, so the idea is use the singleton design pattern.

From your experience, is a singleton good to use with Entity Framework `dbcontext` to ensure that only one `dbcontext` instance is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is singleton good to use with entity framework dbcontext to ensure that one dbcontext instance is used?

It's not only a bad idea, it won't work.  It's not thread-safe and will generate execptions when used concurrently.  And a long-lived DbContext will tend to accumulate lots and lots of objects in its Change Tracker, degrading performance and wasting resources.

> The lifetime of a DbContext begins when the instance is created and
> ends when the instance is disposed. **A DbContext instance is designed
> to be used for a single unit-of-work**. This means that the lifetime of
> a DbContext instance is usually very short.

[DbContext Lifetime, Configuration, and Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)